# Show the usual Schwartz semi-norm is a norm on the Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Define the semi-norm
$$
\|f\|_{a,b}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} |x^af^{(b)}(x)|
$$
where $a,b \in \mathbb Z_+$, and $f^{(b)}$ is the $b$-th derivative of $f$.
Show $\|\cdot\|_{a,b}$ is a norm on the Schwartz space $S(\mathbb R)$.

I don't see how to prove this direction of the nonnegativity requirement for the norm
$$
\|f\|_{a,b} =0 \text{ implies } f=0.
$$

If one of the derivative is zero, how can I infer that the original function is also zero?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $f$ such that $\lVert f\rVert_{a,b}=0$. Then for each $x\neq 0$, we have $f^{(b)}(x)=0$, and as $f^{(b)}$ is continuous, $f^{(b)}(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. This implies that $f$ is a polynomial. As $f$ is assumed to be in the Schwartz space, $f$ [vanishes at infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233609/show-a-schwartz-function-vanish-at-infinity), hence $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Wait. Doesn't this prove Schwartz space is a Banach space? It shouldn't

Comment: @ric.san This just proves that $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{a,b}$ is a norm. It does not prove completeness.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Is there a simple way to disprove completeness?