# Show a Schwartz function vanish at infinity

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be in the Shwartz space $\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$.
Why does the $\mathcal S$-norm
$$
\|f\|_{a,b}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb R} |x^af^{(b)}(x)|, \text{ for } a,b \in \Bbb Z_+,
$$
implies that $f$ vanish at infinity?

The norm gives a bound on 
$$
\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)
$$
but that doesn't show the function vanish.

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/227702/14108) raised this question.

Comment: Well, by definition $xf(x)$ is bounded, so ...

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $C_a:=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}|x^af(x)|$.  As $f$ is in the Schwarz space, $C_a\in\Bbb R$. So we have for all $x\in\Bbb R$ and $a\in\Bbb Z_+$, 
$$|f(x)|\leqslant \frac{C_0+C_a}{1+|x|^a}.$$
In particular, $|f(x)|=O(|x|^{-a})$ for all positive integer $a$, at $
\pm\infty$ (and a constant depending on $a$), so the convergence is faster than polynomial.

Comment: Even $|f(x)| \in o(|x|^{-a})$ (small Oh) for $|x| \to \infty$.