# Possible density of Schwartz Functions in the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, schwartz-space

While reading about Function Spaces [here](https://yannisparissis.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/dmat0101-notes-2-convolution-dense-subspaces-and-interpolation-of-operators/) ; from the chain of inclusions I had some questions that: whether $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^{n})$ (the Schwartz class of functions) is included in $C_{0} (\mathbb R^{n})$ (Space of all continuous functions vanishing at infinity) AND if affirmative, is the inclusion is dense?? i.e. Can we approximate a function in $C_{0} (\mathbb R^{n})$ by a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^{n})$ uniformly???

I found an article [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233609/show-a-schwartz-function-vanish-at-infinity?rq=1) .

So my question is: Can we approximate a function in $C_{0} (\mathbb R^{n})$ by a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^{n})$ uniformly???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Let $f$ be in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Recall that this implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Your claim is easy using [mollifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier). Let me show you how this works.

Pick a smooth positive function $\psi$ with support contained in the open unit ball $B_1(0)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi = 1$. Notice that $\psi$ is clearly a Schwartz function. For $\delta>0$ we define $\psi_\delta(x)=\frac1{\delta^n} \psi(\frac x{\delta})$.

Then $\psi_{\delta}$ is supported inside $B_\delta(0)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi_\delta=1$ (this is why we multiplied by $\delta^{-n}$). So as $\delta$ tends to zero, $\psi_\delta$ becomes more concentrated around the origin. Define

$$f_\delta := f*\psi_\delta.$$

Then $f_\delta\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, because $\psi_\delta$ is Schwartz. We claim that $f_\delta\to f$ in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as $\delta\to 0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ for all $|x-y|<\delta_0$. Thus, if $\delta<\delta_0$ we have for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ arbitrary:

$$|f*\psi_\delta(x)-f(x)| \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\psi_\delta(y)(f(x-y)-f(x))|  dy< \varepsilon\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi_\delta(y) dy=\varepsilon.$$

In the first inequality we used the triangle inequality and used that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi_\delta = 1$. In the second inequality we used that $\psi_\delta$ is supported in $B_\delta(0)$.

This proves the claim.

Comment: So, a function in  $C_{0}(\mathbb R^{n})$ can be approximated by a sequence of functions in $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^{n})$ uniformly; So,$\mathcal S(\mathbb R^{n})$ is dense in  $C_{0}(\mathbb R^{n})$. Isn't it??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So, with due respect may I suggest you to edit the first line of your answer..??

Comment: Oh, now I see, horrible typo. Sorry.

Comment: There is something I don't understand in J.R.'s answer. I don't see why $f_\delta$ must be Schwartz. Take, in one dimension, $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$. It's easy to see that for $\delta$ small one has $f_\delta(x) \ge f(x)/2$, hence $f_\delta$ is not Schwartz. Alternatively, the Fourier transform of $f_\delta$ is $$ \widehat{f_\delta} = \widehat f \; \widehat{\psi_\delta} = c e^{-|x|} \; \widehat{\psi_\delta}
$$
which is not Schwartz, since it is not $C^\infty$. Thus $f_\delta$ cannot be Schwartz. Probably one must truncate $f$ before applying the mollifier.

Comment: @J.R. How can I conclude (from you result and the fact that Schwartz space is dense in $L^1$)  that  the range of Fourier transform on $L^1$ is dense in $C_0$?